# Remove duplicate entries on a column on the go

Tags: microsoft-excel, duplicate

Other than removing duplicates using "Remove Duplicates" function on DATA tab, is there a formula or macro to delete/remove duplicate entries on the go so that I am left with unique values?

[An example below is column A with duplicate entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41sdq.png)

Comment: Your situation isn't clear and without that is impossible to make suggestion. What's your input data format and desired output?

Comment: hello @MátéJuhász, I've simplified the question

Comment: Why not use Remove Duplicates?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad need to delete duplicates on the go as I need to pull out other data using vlookup

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e

Comment: @MátéJuhász thank you. Unfortunately did consider this but MS Excel on work PCs do not have UNIQUE function

Comment: If using a macro, you need to click on something to launch it. If using a formula, you need to make sure the formula is dragged down far enough. Safest and/or quickest method is to just add a Remove Duplicates shortcut to your Quick Access Toolbar at the top. That way you don't need to go through the laborious effort of clicking on the Data tab.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this formula in B2:

=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$9,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$1:B1,$A$2:$A$9),0)),"")

Press **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.
[image]